# Sprite Collision

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm running a collide_mask check, to delete a mob instance on collision with the player sprite.. It works fine.

```
pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, mobs, True, pygame.sprite.collide_mask)
```

What I'm having a hard time with, is making the explosion animation occur at the specific 'mob in 'mobs'' location.

```
minuspoints = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, mobs, True, pygame.sprite.collide_mask)
    for hit in minuspoints:
        life-=5
        score+=1
        if cash-1>=0:
            cash-=1
        else:
            life-=5
        enemies-=1
        if moo==0:
            collision.play()
            ensmallpop.play()

        # Check which mob was hit
        for m in mobs:
            pass

#popAnim
        popco = m.update(pos)
```

How do I determine which mob was hit?

I have 1700 lines of code (perhaps not too effectively written), so at this point I'm juggling quite a few different sections in my head to decide how this would work.

If you need any extra info please ask!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `minuspoints` list contains the mobs that collided with the `player`, so you can just play the explosion animation at the `hit.rect.center` position. I'd recommend to change the variable names `minuspoints` and `hit` to something like `collided_mobs` and `mob`.

```
collided_mobs = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, mobs, True, pygame.sprite.collide_mask)
for mob in collided_mobs:
    explosion_position = mob.rect.center
    # Now create the explosion at `explosion_position`.
```

Comment: Nice, that did the job. Thanks!